# Is it possible to change packagewide global variables during pytest testing?

Tags: python, pytest

In my project, I use a file called 'conf.py' to store several configuration variables, such as a basepath to save files under.

```
# conf.py:
'''
global variables and settings
'''

# Number of nodes in the graph
NODECOUNT = 1206

# save location
BASEPATH = 'data/'
```

Other parts of the package load the variables by importing them from 'conf.py'.
When testing with pytest, I would need other values for those variables to be used by the imported packages. Is this possible somehow?

Edit:
My current pytest file looks like this:

```py
import pytest
import my_packages

# set up a small graph to test on
s = structure(data, name) # structure uses conf.NODECOUNT
save(conf.BASEPATH + name, s)

# Tests
class TestOneClass:
    def test_some_function():
        res = some_function(name) # loads data from 'conf.BASEPATH/name'
        assert res == expected_res
# more tests after
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pytest [monkeypatch fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html) to do this. Assuming you have the aforementioned `conf.py` then a file `test_conf.py` would look like this. This is just an example which tests the value of the configuration, you probably want to do something different with it.

```
import conf

def test_conf(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(conf, 'NODECOUNT', 5)
    assert conf.NODECOUNT == 5
```

If you need to change the configuration in submodules then you need to monkeypatch the `conf` which is imported by those submodules. The approach is the same though. Assume the following folder/file structure:

```
tmp
├── conf.py
├── __init__.py
├── sub
│   ├── calc.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── test_calc.py
```

Then `calc.py` looks like this:

```
from tmp import conf

def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

And `test_calc.py` would look like this:

```
from tmp.sub import calc

def test_add(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(calc.conf, 'NODECOUNT', 5)
    assert calc.add(1, 2) == 3
    assert calc.conf.NODECOUNT == 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question for more clarity. I tried to use your solution to change the values after my imports (outside of a specific test), but am getting a `TypeError: must be absolute import path string, not 'NODECOUNT'`

Comment: Where's `some_function` located? In `my_packages`? And your `conf` is loaded in `my_packages`? Then you can use the below approach to monkeypatch `conf` inside of `my_packages`.

Comment: They are located like you assumed. However, I need the variables redefined when I set up my mockup data. That is before any test, since all tests use the same data.

Comment: Well in that case you can just do a regular import of your configuration and overwrite the values, i.e. `import conf` and then `conf.BASEPATH = 'my test basepath'`. Or what's stopping you from that?

Comment: In that case, the constructors still use the normal conf.py and the test errors before collection

Comment: Well of course you need to do both. Overwrite the values in the setup of the test case and then monkeypatch in your submodules, otherwise they're out of sync!